# IIS handling WCF web method multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, iis

I have problem with WCF web service, especially with web method. I call it from c# client with normal HttpRequest and in IIS logs it seems URL is called only one time but from logs I see that method handling request is called multiple times. Do you have any clue why something like this might happen?

Comment: Could you post some code, and is your c# client an ASP.net form?

Comment: No, client is just console C# application. Web service sends a looot of data, with smaller amount of data it's handled in good way.

Comment: Well the connection will stay open, thats why you will see in IIS that the url is only called once, were as the web method can be called multiple times while the session is open. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with my WCF service (httpBinding) the service was called from a client application only once, yet the server method was called multiple times and every time the method itself finished ok so I figured there must be some problem with the network communication.

I found a way to debug it by enabling tracing in `web.config`

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="d:\logs\Traces.svclog"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

When I looked at the trace log file, it turned out I had a problem with serialization of one of my classes.